# FullCalendar dates and times rendered incorrect rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

FullCalendar implement in my RoR application, and today he is doing tests I realized that the dates and the days are incorrect.
I worked well until this day, create a new application and the same thing happens, today is **Monday, 4 November**, 
and I get that it is not **November 6**

```
var initialize_calendar;
initialize_calendar = function() {
  $('.calendar').each(function(){
    var calendar = $(this);
    calendar.fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        today:    'hoy',
        month:    'month',
        week:     'week',
        day:      'day',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },

      allDayText: "Todo el dia",

      buttonText: {
        today: "Hoy",
        month: "Mes",
        week: "Semana",
        day: "Hoy"
      },

      monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
      monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
      dayNames: ['Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves','Viernes', 'Sabado', 'Domingo'],
      dayNamesShort: ['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mier', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab', 'Dom'],
      defaultView: 'agendaDay',
      selectable: true,
      minTime: '08:00:00',
      maxTime: '20:00:00',
      slotDuration: '00:60:00',
      hiddenDays: [ 5, 6 ],
      selectHelper: true,
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true,
      events: '/events.json',
      timezone: "local",


      select: function(start, end) {
        $.getScript('/events/new', function() {
          $('#event_date_range').val(moment(start).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm") + ' - ' + moment(end).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"))
          date_range_picker();
          $('.start_hidden').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
          $('.end_hidden').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
        });

        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
      },

      eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        event_data = { 
          event: {
            id: event.id,
            start: event.start.format(),
            end: event.end.format()
          }
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: event.update_url,
            data: event_data,
            type: 'PATCH'
        });
      },

      eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        $.getScript(event.edit_url, function() {
          $('#event_date_range').val(moment(event.start).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm") + ' - ' + moment(event.end).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"))
          date_range_picker();
          $('.start_hidden').val(moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
          $('.end_hidden').val(moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
        });
      }
    });
  })
};
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', initialize_calendar);
```

Comment: It displays correctly when tested [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRFYE/682/)?

Comment: If you hide on Saturday and Sunday, the error happens. @Rhono

Comment: How are you hiding those days? I tried with `weekends: false` but it looks OK. Feel free to link an updated jsfiddle

Comment: the error occurs when translated into Spanish day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My inability to read Spanish meant I couldn't see the error ;)

You need to start your `dayNames` & `dayNamesShort` arrays with Domingo. [FullCalendar docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/dayNames/).

```
dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'],
dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mier', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab']
```